# How to install PHP 5.x version with Apache 2.0 and PHP 7.x version with Apache 2.4 in Ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: php, apache

I'm setting up two servers in a single Ubuntu 16.04 machine with PHP version 5.x with Apache 2.0 and PHP version 7.x with Apache 2.4.

I don't have prior experience setting up this. Kindly help.

Comment: This might be better to ask on the https://askubuntu.com/ site

Comment: IMHO - docker would be a good solution.

Comment: Hi Hannah, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Stack Overflow is primarily focussed on programming problems, and while I recognise you are probably setting up your dev environment, this question probably does more appropriately belong on either SuperUser or AskUbuntu https://superuser.com/tour

Comment: Thanks. I will post this question in askubuntu.com.